# getCurrentPossition возвращает только 0

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Хотел реализовать кнопки старта/паузы в notification'e, но метод getCurrentPosition никак не выдает реальное число, только 0.

```
public void songStream(int songPos){
    player.reset();
    songPosition = songPos;
    playSong = songList.get(songPosition);
    currSong = playSong.getId();
    Log.i(TAG,"Artist "+playSong.getArtist()+" Song "+playSong.getTitle());
    trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId
            (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    currSong);
    try {
        player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),trackUri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        player.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    player.start();
}
```

Здесь я обрабатываю нажатия из notofication:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    songStream(songPosition);
    showNotification();
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.PREV_ACTION)){
        try{
            songStream(songPosition-1);
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            songStream(songList.size()-1);
        }
        count=0;
        showNotification();
        Log.i(TAG, "Clicked Previous");
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.PLAY_ACTION)) {
        player.pause();
        pausePosition=player.getCurrentPosition();
        ++count;
        showNotification();
        Log.i(TAG, "Clicked Play Current position "+pausePosition);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.PAUSE_ACTION)) {
        player.seekTo(pausePosition);
        player.start();
        ++count;
        showNotification();
        Log.i(TAG, "Clicked Pause");
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.NEXT_ACTION)){
        try{
            songStream(songPosition+1);
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            songStream(0);
        }
        count=0;
        showNotification();
        Log.i(TAG, "Clicked Next");}
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Переменной pausePosition я присвоил player.getCurrentPosition, т.е. после нажатия на кнопку старта, песня должна воспроизводиться с того момента, как была нажата кнопка паузы. Вопрос: что же мешает получить getCurrentPosition реальную позицию в песне, а не 0?

Comment: В `onStartCommand` у Вас первым идёт безусловный вызов `songStream(songPosition);` , в котором плеер сбрасывается и загружает тот же трек сначала.

Comment: Т.е нужно задать условие, при котором songStream будет вызываться только при условии, что плеер не активен?

Comment: В принципе, можно перенести его в условие, когда юзер нажал плей (у Вас `PAUSE_ACTION` почему-то), в остальных случаях он и так вызывается или не требуется.

Comment: Замечание по коду: `try-catch` на `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - это не хорошее решение, лучше условие, сравнивающее переменную `songPosition` с нулём в `PREV_ACTION` и с `songList.size()` в `NEXT_ACTION`. И при переключении Вы не запоминаете новый номер трека (то есть next->next->next перезапускает один и тот же трек).

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь все работает)